# push notification to specific device from another using firebase android java

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need your help with my code, I need to send a notification when a user does action from his app to notify another user(which I have his device token).

**What I already did:**
first, install node.js and from it download firebase admin SDK and login and connect it to my project on firebase until I got Firebase CLI connected successfully.

then I opened the index.js file and add this code to it:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//import admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/YourNode/{pushId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log('Push notification event triggered');

    //  Get the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const valueObject = change.after.val(); 

    // Create a notification
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: valueObject.title,
            body: valueObject.message,
            sound: "default"
        }
    };

    //Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("pushNotifications", payload, options);
});
```

and then I return to cmd screen and enter firebase deploy but at this point, it returns an error which is:

[image: after firebase deploy]

and when I google this problem I figured that I need to pay for a membership to firebase, right?

**What I need**

1- If that's right is my code and my steps right? and what should I do next to get the notifications working?

2- Can you help to give me the right and specific steps to accomplish that?

*Please* don't give me any link to firebase, I read All of the documentation and really confused.

Thanks for your time, waiting for your help :)

Comment: Just to clarify: the exact case is that you need to send a push message to somebody else upon some request to your node.js app? And where do you host your node.js app?

Comment: @mrpasqal From the code shared and the tagging that seems to be [Firebase's Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Comment: Answer on the one question I could is below. If the questions #1 and #2 still apply with that answer, please edit your question to show what the problem is when you run this code.

Comment: @mrpasqal I am trying to use Firebase cloud function to send that push notifications in case the other user app sleep

Answer (score 1):

> I figured that I need to pay for a membership to firebase, right?

If your code requires Node.js 10 or higher, it can no longer be deployed on Firebase's free plan, and you'll indeed need to be on the pay-as-you-go plan. The error message you get also explicitly mentions this. I recommend studying the [Firebase pricing FAQ on Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-pricing), as it's quite complicated and I don't want to misquote that.

Comment: Thanks for reply,  I need to be sure I am doing the right steps to get the notification? If so l will pay for a plan.